# Python sys path one up from where expected with flask app

Tags: python, flask

### SETUP

File structure:

```
/home/michael/terminal/src/
           |---- __init__.py
           |---- main.py
```

This is my python path (only the first path in the array is noteworthy):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
['/home/michael/terminal', '/home/michael/.venv/terminal/bin', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/michael/.venv/terminal/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Flask env variable:

```
$ env
...
FLASK_APP=/home/michael/terminal/src/main.py
...
```

Start flask app with:

```
cd /home/michael/terminal/src
flask run
```

### QUESTION

Why is the python path `/home/michael/terminal` instead of `/home/michael/terminal/src` ?

### File structure EDIT:

If I remove the `__init__.py` from below, then in sys path it becomes `/home/michael/terminal/src/`, but then I loose the ability to import some modules. Why does flask not allow the flask app to be a module?

```
/home/michael/terminal/src/
           |---- __init__.py
           |---- main.py
```

### PYTHON DOCS

[The python docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default (by convention including a site-packages directory, handled by the site module).

Note the part about "The directory containing the input script", for me I am seeing it adds the directory above that.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Duplicate of [Use __init__.py to modify sys path is a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516849/use-init-py-to-modify-sys-path-is-a-good-idea).